# javascript, jquery idk

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this array:

```
backgrounds: 
       {
        bc2:     '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bc2.jpg',
        codmw2:  '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/codmw2_6.jpg',
        bf2:     '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bf2.jpg',
        bf2142:  '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bf2142.jpg',
        codbo:   '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/codbo.jpg',
        cod5waw: '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/cod5waw.jpg'
       }
```

and I want to access this like `backgrounds[0] = '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bc2.jpg'`.
Is this possible or do I need to create the array in another way?

Comment: please place comment on downvote!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, backgrounds is an object, i.e., an associative array. You can't use numerical indexes now to access its members. You can iterate through it using `for( var prop in backgrounds)` or you can address its members directly (`backgrounds.bc2 or backgrounds['bc2']`).

Answer (score 0):

I should do it like this:

```
var backgrounds = 
   {
    bc2:     '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bc2.jpg',
    codmw2:  '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/codmw2_6.jpg',
    bf2:     '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bf2.jpg',
    bf2142:  '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bf2142.jpg',
    codbo:   '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/codbo.jpg',
    cod5waw: '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/cod5waw.jpg'
   };
backgrounds.bc2 = "test";
console.log(backgrounds.bc2) //test
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thecheesewheel/wrW2C/) and it worked

```
var backgrounds = {
                bc2:     '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bc2.jpg',
                codmw2:  '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/codmw2_6.jpg',
                bf2:     '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bf2.jpg',
                bf2142:  '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bf2142.jpg',
                codbo:   '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/codbo.jpg',
                cod5waw: '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/cod5waw.jpg',
                0:     '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bc2.jpg',
                1:  '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/codmw2_6.jpg',
                2:     '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bf2.jpg',
                3:  '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/bf2142.jpg',
                4:   '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/codbo.jpg',
                5: '/images/layout/images/backgrounds/cod5waw.jpg'
               };

alert(backgrounds[0]);
```

So you could automate this with a loop to avoid duplication errors

```
        var i = 0;
        for(var prop in backgrounds) {
            if(prop.search(/^\d+$/) == -1) { //avoid the infinite loop
                backgrounds[i] = backgrounds[prop];
                i++;
            }
        }
```

of course this means you have duplication of data

Comment: interesting solution. maybe little to complicated but interesting. seems to work on different browsers IE7,8 FF Chrome

Comment: The problem with this is the mixing of metaphors. Most people would expect that backgrounds[0] would refer to the *first* element, not the 7th (or wherever it shows up—associative arrays don't necessarily give you elements in the order you would expect). In other words, you have solved the problem by defeating the expectations of the person who will have to maintain your code. Happy now?

Comment: It even works in IE6, but not a really 'clean' solution, but still interesting ;)

Comment: @Robusto hey, just giving the OP what he wants. It's Christmas! You could add setter/getter methods and put the lookup behind an interface instead, I suppose.

Comment: @oracle certified professional: A baby might want to play with a loaded gun; should you give it to him? Besides, it's not even Thanksgiving yet. =P

Comment: @Robusto it depends. Do I like this baby?